# Displaying a confirmation message after doing a query with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to call a function with Javascript, HTML, AJAX, and PHP.
I am still new to Javascript, AJAX, and PHP.

Background info: I am trying to add a new customer to my database but I am now trying to get a confirmation message on the same page without the page refreshing.

This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addCustomer(ln,fn,pn,dob)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","addCustomer.php?add_LN="+ln+"?add_FN="+fn+"?add_PN="+pn+"?add_DOB="+dob,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
            <form action="return addCustomer(this.add_LN, this.add_FN, this.add_PN, this.add_DOB);">
                <input type="text" name="add_LN" id="add_LN" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="add_FN" id="add_FN" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="add_PN" id="add_PN" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="add_DOB" id="add_DOB" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" name="add_Customer" id="add_Customer" value="Add Customer" />
            </form>
            <span id="txtHint"></span>
          </p>        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
```

I get a "This link appears broken"
With:
http://127.0.0.1/cpsc471/return%20addCustomer(this.add_LN,%20this.add_FN,%20this.add_PN,%20this.add_DOB);?add_LN=ee&add_FN=123&add_PN=eee&add_DOB=eee&add_Customer=Add+Customer
in the url bar.

What am I doing wrong? :) I do not want the page to refresh. I am trying to just get the confirmation or non-confirmation to display.

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery for your AJAX? That would make your code much nicer.

Comment: Although I hate answers starting with 'Use jQuery', in this case I'd suggest you [use jQuery](http://jquery.com/)...

Comment: @thiefmaster, because sometimes it is better to first learn what the framework is doing for you when before you start using the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 <form action="return addCustomer(this.add_LN, this.add_FN, this.add_PN, this.add_DOB);">
```

You don't want the form action to be a javascript call, you need to do this onclick or something.

*The arguments above by @thiefmaster and @martin are correct: using jquery is much simpler. You are right about the framework thing, but in this case you need to go and code for a lot of troubles (responses, when is there a successfull AJAX call, different browsers etc)*

Comment: Thanks, I've switched it to be onSubmit, but it keeps refreshing so I do not think I see the result. Is there anything you recommend?

Comment: I would start with a simple "alert" instead of the ajax code, to see if your code is called correctly. Then add the javascript code, also in steps. Maybe first call something, and on success/200 do an alert. then try to actually give some response with getElementById() etc.

Answer (score 1):

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

// put your codes here like

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

//  document.getElementById("show_label").innerHTML='text as you wish like updated enjoy';

```
}
```

}
And add a label with the id of show_label